# Can't upload video in symfony2.7

Tags: php, symfony, video, upload

I'm trying to make a form with file field to upload videos and audios files.
I can upload audio files but not videos.
When I upload MP3 file the extension is .mpga and not .mp3.

Here is my Code, (I autorized all type of files to avoid problemes with mimetypes) :

```
        $product = new Bfile();
        $form_upload = $this->createForm(new BfileType(), $product);
        $form_upload->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form_upload->isValid()) {
            // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
            /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */

            $file = $product->getBrochure();

            // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

            // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
            $brochuresDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads';
            $file->move($brochuresDir, $fileName);

            // instead of its contents
            $product->setBrochure($fileName);

            // ... persist the $product variable or any other work

            return $this->render(...);
        }
```

My Form :

```
<?php

namespace RS\VideosBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('brochure', 'file')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RS\VideosBundle\Entity\Bfile'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'rs_videosbundle_bfile';
    }
}
```

My Entity :

```
<?php

namespace RS\VideosBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Bfile
 */
class Bfile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\File(maxSize ="1000M")
     */
    private $brochure;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set brochure
     *
     * @param string $brochure
     *
     * @return Bfile
     */
    public function setBrochure($brochure)
    {
        $this->brochure = $brochure;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brochure
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBrochure()
    {
        return $this->brochure;
    }
}
```

I get No Error But there are no video files in My uploads folder.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any form errors in your template?

Comment: Hi, Jahller, No I don't any errors

Answer (score 5):

I would say there are multiple things that looks strange:

## 1 - limit on file uploads on php / webserver

- check your limits in php.ini look for
  `upload_max_filesize = xxM` and `post_max_size = xxM`
- check your limit in webserver config apache/nginx
  for nginx its `client_max_body_size 8m;`
  apache should use php.ini values.

## 2 - filename extension problem

- this souldn't be the main cause of the problem but
- the problem with extension is very likely because of the extensionGuesser eg. this line `$fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();` This will rename the file with extension by its MimeType - it doesn't matter what your file name is, like test.txt - when its mime type is mpeg layer3 it will change it to mp3.

from guesser class:

```
/**
 * Returns the extension based on the mime type.
 *
 * If the mime type is unknown, returns null.
 *
 * This method uses the mime type as guessed by getMimeType()
 * to guess the file extension.
 *
 * @return string|null The guessed extension or null if it cannot be guessed
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @see ExtensionGuesser
 * @see getMimeType()
 */
public function guessExtension()
{
    $type = $this->getMimeType();
    $guesser = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance();

    return $guesser->guess($type);
}
```

## 3 - try removing validation

- just try it for debuging sake.

Comment: Hi Nakashu ,, The  php.ini is well configured, I don't have probleme with size <= 1M, but still have probleme with big size videos and audios,,, when i try to upload videos with size > 500M my computer is blocked,, I don't understand why.